# Docker and http url of started web application

Tags: scala, docker

I would like to run my web application in docker (written in `java/scala`). So as a result I created the following docker file:

```
FROM java
ADD 0/backend-assembly-1.1.jar /app/backend-assembly-1.1.jar
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "\/app\/backend-assembly-1.1.jar", "0.0.0.0", "80"]
```

Application indeed start successfully when I run it with `docker run` command:

```
[DEBUG] [02/12/2017 21:28:56.940] [tkachuko-web-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://tkachuko-web-system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Successfully bound to /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:80
```

I do understand that docker images run on virtual machine so I decided to find out IP address of the virtual box machine:

```
docker inspect 7cf588493b41 | grep IP
```

and it returned `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"`.

**However neither `0.0.0.0`, `localhost` or `172.17.0.2` are accessible**, but when I run everything without docker (from command line) everything does work. **Could you please specify which address my application can be accessed?**

Just in case: I am using OS X.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be usable outside of Docker, you need to bind the port in the container to a port on the hosting system. You have not included your run command, but it would need to be something like this.

```
    docker run -d -p 8080:80 <image-name>
```

The key here is the `-p` (or `--publish`) flag, which binds a local port to a container port.

```
-p local-port:container-port

-p 80:80              # bind local port 80 to container's port 80
-p 8080:80            # bind local port 8080 to container's port 80
```

You can also bind the port only to your Mac's localhost if you prefer.

```
-p 127.0.0.1:8080:80
```

In all of the above cases, the local port you've bound should now answer on localhost, i.e.

http://localhost:8080/

You would normally also include the port in an `EXPOSE` statement in Dockerfile (and you have done so) but it's not technically required to publish the port.

Comment: Thanks you very much, sir. Works like a charm and explanations are quite helpful. I found about `-p` just after I submitted the question :) But this answer will be definitely useful for anyone starting to use docker.

Comment: I haven't used EXPOSE and the mapping still works. I used -p 9080:8080 and localhost:9080 works.

Comment: @Asif EXPOSE is recommended but technically optional. I clarified the answer.